# Trying to use axios.put but cannot the file param to work with a local path

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

Hi i am trying to upload an image taken on my phone to my AWS S3 account.  Hardly a new concept i realize but i'm new to JS and react-native.

I have been successful with similar code when the imagefile comes off an Input component in a web app but how do i use this code with a local path ?

I attempt below to use fs.readfile with the local path however the upload still fails.

1. is this the right way to do this ?
2. am i using readfile incorrectly ?

Thanks in advance if you can assist !

code extract :

```
uploadFile = (filepath,signedS3request) => {

        return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {

            let fileParts = filepath.split('.');
            let fileType = fileParts[1];

            var options = {
                headers: {'Content-Type': fileType}
            }
            fs.readFile(filepath)
            .then(imageFile => {
                axios.put(signedS3request,imageFile,options)
                .then(result => {
                    console.log('fileupload success:',result);
                    resolve('success')
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('fileupload failed:',error);
                    reject('failed file upload')
                })

            }).catch(error => {
                console.log('fileupload : cannot read file : ', filepath);
                reject('failed to read file for upload')
            })

        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use form-data and for this.

check out example.

```
const concat = require("concat-stream")
const FormData = require('form-data');
const fs = require('fs');
uploadFile = (filepath,signedS3request) => {    
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {

        const fd = new FormData();

        fd.append("foo", "bar")
        fd.append("file", fs.createReadStream(filepath))

        fd.pipe(concat({encoding: 'buffer'}, data => {
          axios.put(signedS3request, data, {
            headers: fd.getHeaders()
          }).then(result => {
                console.log('fileupload success:',result);
                resolve('success')
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('fileupload failed:',error);
                reject('failed file upload')
            })
        }))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Miral, i'm hoping i can get your code to work but am getting this strange error : " ReferenceError : Can't find variable : Buffer.    ever seen this before ?

Comment: Actually Miral i have a whole new additional problem now.  can seem to use 'fs' in my project at all.

Comment: error: Error: While trying to resolve module `fs` from file `/...../src/datapass.js`, the package `/..../node_modules/fs/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/..../node_modules/fs/index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist: